# Display specific rownames in a heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap

I want to show specific names on a heatmap. Names are specified in a separate list. Here is my approach:

```
labRow <- c("A", "B", "C")
heatmap.2(x, labRow = labRow)
```

Please note A, B, and C, exist among other rownames in x.

Comment: Your code works. What is your problem ?

Comment: no, because it has to use existing annotations, and only name these that match with the list in the final heatmap

Comment: a similar problem was described here: https://www.biostars.org/p/158613/ but I don't find the solution particularly elegant